# Bitbake do image failure

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I have been successfully building an image for many days now. I add all of my custom files to GitLab. I have not knowingly made changes to my build environment. I am now getting errors can can not build my image. Can anyone understand what this error is telling me? I have tried looking it up but nothing seems to work.

```
Initialising tasks: 100% |##################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:06
Sstate summary: Wanted 5 Local 3 Network 0 Missed 2 Current 1114 (60% match, 99% complete)
NOTE: Executing Tasks
ERROR: evccapplication-1.0-r0 do_image: Error executing a python function in exec_python_func() autogenerated:

The stack trace of python calls that resulted in this exception/failure was:
File: 'exec_python_func() autogenerated', lineno: 2, function: <module>
     0001:
 *** 0002:do_image(d)
     0003:
File: '/home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/sources/poky/meta/classes/image.bbclass', lineno: 262, function: do_image
     0258:
     0259:    d.setVarFlag('REPRODUCIBLE_TIMESTAMP_ROOTFS', 'export', '1')
     0260:    pre_process_cmds = d.getVar("IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND")
     0261:
 *** 0262:    execute_pre_post_process(d, pre_process_cmds)
     0263:}
     0264:do_image[dirs] = "${TOPDIR}"
     0265:addtask do_image after do_rootfs
     0266:
File: '/home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/sources/poky/meta/lib/oe/utils.py', lineno: 263, function: execute_pre_post_process
     0259:    for cmd in cmds.strip().split(';'):
     0260:        cmd = cmd.strip()
     0261:        if cmd != '':
     0262:            bb.note("Executing %s ..." % cmd)
 *** 0263:            bb.build.exec_func(cmd, d)
     0264:
     0265:# For each item in items, call the function 'target' with item as the first
     0266:# argument, extraargs as the other arguments and handle any exceptions in the
     0267:# parent thread
File: '/home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py', lineno: 256, function: exec_func
     0252:    with bb.utils.fileslocked(lockfiles):
     0253:        if ispython:
     0254:            exec_func_python(func, d, runfile, cwd=adir)
     0255:        else:
 *** 0256:            exec_func_shell(func, d, runfile, cwd=adir)
     0257:
     0258:    try:
     0259:        curcwd = os.getcwd()
     0260:    except:
File: '/home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/build.py', lineno: 503, function: exec_func_shell
     0499:    with open(fifopath, 'r+b', buffering=0) as fifo:
     0500:        try:
     0501:            bb.debug(2, "Executing shell function %s" % func)
     0502:            with open(os.devnull, 'r+') as stdin, logfile:
 *** 0503:                bb.process.run(cmd, shell=False, stdin=stdin, log=logfile, extrafiles=[(fifo,readfifo)])
     0504:        except bb.process.ExecutionError as exe:
     0505:            # Find the backtrace that the shell trap generated
     0506:            backtrace_marker_regex = re.compile(r"WARNING: Backtrace \(BB generated script\)")
     0507:            stdout_lines = (exe.stdout or "").split("\n")
File: '/home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/sources/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/process.py', lineno: 186, function: run
     0182:
     0183:    if pipe.returncode != 0:
     0184:        if log:
     0185:            # Don't duplicate the output in the exception if logging it
 *** 0186:            raise ExecutionError(cmd, pipe.returncode, None, None)
     0187:        raise ExecutionError(cmd, pipe.returncode, stdout, stderr)
     0188:    return stdout, stderr
Exception: bb.process.ExecutionError: Execution of '/home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/build-fb/tmp/work/imx6ull14x14evk-poky-linux-gnueabi/evccapplication/1.0-r0/temp/run.prelink_image.131394' failed with exit code 2

ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/build-fb/tmp/work/imx6ull14x14evk-poky-linux-gnueabi/evccapplication/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_image.131394
ERROR: Task (/home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/evcc_layers/meta-evccapplication/recipes-core/images/evccapplication.bb:do_image) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 3064 tasks of which 3063 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/michael/Documents/evcc_custom/evcc_layers/meta-evccapplication/recipes-core/images/evccapplication.bb:do_image
Summary: There were 2 WARNING messages shown.
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get an error similar to this delete your build folder. Then recreate it. For NXP devices they give you the command

```
DISTRO=fsl-imx-fb MACHINE=imx6ull14x14evk source imx-setup-release.sh -b build-fb
```

Save your `local.conf` and `bblayers.bb` file to git or to a new location.
Delete the `build-fb` folder and re-run the command above. Pull in any changes from git or files saved elsewhere.

Re-run bitbake. This got my workspace back. Because you are not deleting any of the downloads folders the build takes little time. All the time is spent compiling sources.